# Dynamically change _target="blank" to _target="self" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a page with a fair few links, the links currently are target="blank" so if someone accidentally clicks on one they won't ruin what their doing on my page. However, I don't like doing _target="blank" (I always think it's sort of patronising for the user to tell them how to open a link..).

So I thought I'd give the user the option to turn 'open in new window / tab' off. Currently I'm doing this in PHP:

```
<?php if($newWindow){ echo '_blank'; } ?>
```

But I would much rather do this in JavaScript if possible (seems silly to reload the whole page just to change a few strings). How would I do that? I've found lots on changing input fields and the like, but not link attributes..

Oh, and not in jQuery if at all possible. If it is possible using CSS that would be cool, but I'm assuming it's not come quite that far yet..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: Ah brill - don't know how I missed that :/ I'll add an answer or edit to show when its' working in case anyone else needs it..

Comment: No need to use `.setAttribute()`. Things like the "target" attribute are exposed as properties on the DOM nodes, so you can just get a reference to the node and set the "target" property directly.

Comment: Why not do anything at all, take default behaviour and let users choose themselves to open in new page or not. We can ctrl-click or middlemouse-click if we want.

Comment: 'tis what I would normally do - however for this site, which is geared towards less browser-savvy people (ie. older people..), and it's quite an interactive page.. don't want them navigating away by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere on your page (should be `true`/`false`):

```
var newWindow = <?=$newWindow;?>
```

Then do (jQuery, just concept though):

```
$('a').bind('click', function(event){
    if(newWindow){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

There are a few ways of doing it, but this one came to mind first. This obviously requires you to also handle relative links - so keep that in mind.

Edit: Due to @durbnpoisn giving me greif, here's the code ready for you to drop into your site:

Link:

```
<a id="toggle-new-tab">Turn on/off new window</a>
```

JS:

```
var newWindow = false;
document.getElementById('toggle-new-tab').onclick = function(){
    newWindow = !newWindow;
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    if(links[i].href !== '')
        links[i].onclick = newWindowHandler;
}

function newWindowHandler(event){
    if(newWindow){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(event.target.href);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qY7sh/1/

Comment: He specifically said "no jQuerry".

Comment: @durbnpoisn and I specifically said "(jQuery, just concept though)" - If I'd just written it in pseudo code would that have been better for you? Jeez.

Comment: The point is, it shouldn't be here at all.  Even in concept, it is NOT an answer to his question.  Is it a better solution?  Maybe.  But it is specifically what he did not ask for.

Comment: Well that's your opinion, but I believe this does what he wants. All he needs to do is set newWindow to `true`/`false` in javascript.

Comment: It's not just my opinion.  It's what he said.  And it's not just that simple.  Because it won't work without referencing the jQuerry libraries first.  Which, presumably, he's not doing.

Comment: It's exactly that - it's your opinion. And I'm not suggesting he takes my code and dumps it in his project, as I've said it's the concept. How hard is this for you to grasp?

Comment: Thank you so much! Works fine! Sorry for the delay, turns out I was being an idiot: loading the script before the links made nothing happen..after it's all fine (probably rather obviously) - anyone else using this, put ya script at the bottom of the page! Cheer dude! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("[anchor id]").target = "_blank";
```

This should work, assuming your "a href" has an ID.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wanted, he specifically said "I've got a page with a **fair few links**..." - this only targets one item - what's he supposed to do, write this out lots of times? I should really -1 you considering you didn't give OP exactly what he wanted.

Comment: Also, this wont work, it'll give OP an undefined function error.

Comment: should also be `_blank`, not `self`, bud

Comment: Fixed, as per your suggestion.  Why don't we let the OP decide what he likes better?  Whereas your answer is more technically correct, it's not what he wanted.  My answer, while not the best solution, for the reasons you mentioned, IS what he asked for.

Comment: You're right, it is what OP wanted :) have a nice day

Comment: This did turn out to be useful for another (similar) issue - so thanks for this also!